# Solve a summation with generating functions and Burnside's lemma

Tags: combinatorics, summation

I'm working on proofs, and I came across the concepts generating functions and Burnside's lemma.
So the summation is this:
$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(2n-2k){n \choose k} = n2^{n}
$. 
(If someone could format this that would be great).

How would you proove this summation using generating functions? 
How is Burnside's lemma used to solve this problem also?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(2n-2k){n \choose k}
=2\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(n-k){n \choose k}
=2\sum_{k=1}^{n}k{n \choose k}
$.

Comment: So how would this work? Would I need to multiply 2 generating functions together?

Comment: No, Get the generating function for $(1+x)^n$ and differentiate it.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with 
$$n \, (1+ t)^{n-1} = \frac{d}{dt} (1 + t)^{n} = \frac{d}{dt} \, \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} \, t^{k} = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} \, k \, t^{k-1}$$
then
$$2^{n} \, n = 2 \, \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} \, k.$$
Now, 
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} \, k = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} \, (n-k)$$ 
and leads to
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} \, (2 n - 2k) = 2^{n} \, n.$$